# Jquery increase value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to increase a value fetched from the DOM.
The value is stuck in "1";
What am i doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-1">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddFlak">+ Flak</button>
</div>
<div class="well" id="flakDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var flakNr = 1;
//Create flak
$('#btnAddFlak').on('click', function () {

//Set flakNr
var flakNr = $('.flakMiddle').last().val();
console.log(flakNr);

//Increase flakNr
flakNr++;
console.log(flakNr);


//Flak HTML setup
var flak = $('<div class="flak nopadding"><div class="flakSideUp nopadding"></div><div class="flakMiddle">Flak <b>' + flakNr + '</b></div><div class="flakSideDown nopadding"></div></div><br>');

//Insert flak to flakDiv
$('#flakDiv').append(flak);


});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7hqu377v/

Comment: In your example at the begining you don't have element for selector '.flakMiddle' so at first flakNR is NaN (Not a number)

Comment: Yes, I can make an if case for this.. but this is not my main problem!?

Comment: there is no ".flakMiddle" in your jsfiddle, thus it won't work there (i.e. will always display a NaN the first time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified your code a bit

http://jsfiddle.net/7hqu377v/1/

added `<span>` inside your `div.flakMiddle` which holds actual number. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Even the if i got for free ;D

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that maybe you could have another variable to increment like:

```
var flakNr = 1;
var ctr= 0; // or any number you want

//Create flak
$('#btnAddFlak').on('click', function () {

//Set flakNr
var flakNr = $('.flakMiddle').last().val();
console.log(flakNr);

//Increase flakNr with the value ctr
flakNr+=ctr;

// increment ctr
ctr++;

console.log(flakNr);


//Flak HTML setup
var flak = $('<div class="flak nopadding"><div class="flakSideUp nopadding"></div><div class="flakMiddle">Flak <b>' + flakNr + '</b></div><div class="flakSideDown nopadding"></div></div><br>');

//Insert flak to flakDiv
$('#flakDiv').append(flak);


});
```

And that's it your good to go! Happy coding..